# How to convert a DictProxy object into JSON serializable dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a `DictProxy` object created using `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` to support concurrency. At the end of the run, I need to serialize the dict to JSON. But it's unclear how to convert the `DictProxy` to serializable dict object. When I tried it, I got:

```
TypeError: <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x10a240ed0> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Rather than using a private `DictProxy` method like `_getvalue()`, I'd prefer using a public one like `copy()` which returns a shallowly-copied `dict`.

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    d = manager.dict()
    import json
    json.dumps(d.copy())
```

Comment: Despite the naming convention, `_getvalue()` is documented, so it's not really private. It's also the only option for objects that don't have a `copy` method, though `copy` works fine for the `dict` case.

Comment: @dano: Documented ≠ Public

Comment: Core Python devs have stated that the documented parts of the API are the de-facto public API (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-November/105667.html).

Comment: @dano: Among other things the linked message says "What we're talking about in this thread is what to do in the grey area
of APIs which are not included in the official documentation, but also
don't have names starting with an underscore so they 'look public'
when reading the source code or exploring the API in the interactive
interpreter." In _this_ case what we have is something that is in the official documentation, but doesn't "look public" since its name starts with an underscore, so your rationale seems bogus IMO. It's also not necessary since the `copy` method is available.

Comment: He says pretty clearly "The standard library documentation should say that the public API is
what the documentation says it is.". The documentation documents `_getvalue` (and `_callmethod`, which looks private based on the name as well). It's part of the public API.

Comment: @GoingMyWay: Unsure what you were _trying_ to say — but I just verified this works in Python 3.8.2.

Comment: @martineau I mean I do not know why it does not work in Python 3.7, the `d.copy()`.

Comment: @GoingMyWay: What do you mean it doesn't work? How exactly - what happens?

Comment: @martineau It still shows the model `TypeError: <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x10a240ed0> is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: @martineau You can try this code `import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    d = manager.dict()
    d['dsd'] = 1
    d['b'] = manager.dict()
    d['b']['c'] = 1
    import json
    json.dumps(d.copy(), indent=4)`

Comment: @GoingMyWay: It's because `d['b'] = manager.dict()` creates a _nested_ `manager.dict()`. I don't think you need to do that if the outer dictionary is a `manager.dict()`, and that regular dictionary would work — so try `d['b'] = dict()`. You might also need to use `copy.deepcopy(d)` to make the copy, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @martineau I think it is very common to use nested manager.dict() in multiprocessing. The simplest way to avoid `TypeError: <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x10a240ed0> is not JSON serializable` is to use for loop to get all the data and save to a normal dict.

Comment: @GoingMyWay: It might be common, but I don't think it's necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`dict_proxy._getvalue()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseProxy._getvalue) to fetch the actual `dict` instance underlying the proxy, and pass that to `json.dump` (or whatever method you're using).

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> m = multiprocessing.Manager()
>>> d = m.dict()
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 367, in encode
    chunks = list(self.iterencode(o))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 317, in _iterencode
    for chunk in self._iterencode_default(o, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 323, in _iterencode_default
    newobj = self.default(o)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 344, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x97eed0> is not JSON serializable
>>> json.dumps(d._getvalue())
'{}'
```

Comment: The `d` is empty, what if there are some data in `d`, I think it will throw the `TypeError: <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x97eed0> is not JSON serializable`. Try this code `import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    d = manager.dict()
    d['dsd'] = 1
    d['b'] = manager.dict()
    d['b']['c'] = 1
    import json
    json.dumps(d._getvalue(), indent=4)`

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but I solved the following errors:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'DictProxy' is not JSON serializable
TypeError: Object of type 'ListProxy' is not JSON serializable
```

using:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()

# For Dicts
x = manager.dict()
json.dumps(dict(x))

# For Lists
x = manager.list()
json.dumps(list(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another late answer, with an even simpler approach:
Just add .copy() to the Dict variable in the return line

```
manager = Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()
return return_dict.copy()
```