# Convert nested dictproxy dicts to dicts for JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-multiprocessing

I have a big nested dict `nested_dict` which was created using parallel processing, resulting in DictProxy objects at each level. To avoid having to re-run the creation of this dict which takes hours I want to save everything in a JSON file. As per [How to convert a DictProxy object into JSON serializable dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947581/how-to-convert-a-dictproxy-object-into-json-serializable-dict) it is possible to convert a DictProxy object to a dict, and then make it JSON. But since I have DictProxy objects nested, running `json.dumps(nested_dict.copy())` returns `TypeError: Object of type DictProxy is not JSON serializable`.

Is there an efficient way to recursively convert all DictProxy objects to dict to allow saving in a JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some dict comprehension and a little recursion here:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
from multiprocessing.managers import DictProxy


def get_value(d):
    return {
        key: get_value(sub_d)
        if isinstance(sub_d, DictProxy) else sub_d 
        for key, sub_d in d.items()
            }


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Manager() as manager:

        d1, d2, d3 = manager.dict(), manager.dict(), manager.dict()

        d3['d'] = 'end of nested levels'
        d2['d3'] = d3
        d1['d2'] = d2

        print(d1)
        print(get_value(d1))
```

**Output**

```
{'d2': <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x236493f1f70>}
{'d2': {'d3': {'d': 'end of nested levels'}}}
```

As a bonus, this would even work if there were no `DictProxy` objects or the dictionary wasn't nested

Answer (score 0):

Simply creating a new empty dict and populating it using for loops over the keys until the most inner dict solved it:

```
new_dict = {}
for first_key in nested_dict.keys():
    new_dict[first_key] = {}
    for second_key in nested_dict[first_key].keys():
        new_dict[first_key][second_key] = {}
        ...
        for last_key in nested_dict[first_key][second_key][...][last_key].keys():
            new_dict[first_key][second_key][...][last_key] = a_dictproxy_object.copy()
```

And then

```
import json
with open("my.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(new_dict,f)
```

Maybe it isn't the most effective, but it works!

Comment: It might work now but hardcoding the number of nested levels would be a nightmare to maintain.